# Ergonomic 4000 suddenly stopped working, a key stuck and letters typing randomly

Tags: keyboard, macbook, operating-systems, keyboard-layout

Ok, didn't spill anything or the like, just typing and suddenly my keyboard stops working. Seems like the windows key was stuck, because almost every key I pressed I hear Mac OSX's "beep" when you make an incorrect input and clicking gave the the right-click options.

Trying to type in textedit was impossible, pressing t switched the last two characters, g would scroll the cursor. Restarted, same thing. Think the keyboard is shot but no idea how it happened! Any suggestions on testing what's wrong with it? This will be the third ergonomic 4000 I've bought in a year..

Answer (score 0):

I had a Ergo 2000 with the same problem, it looks like a lot of people had this problem. I call to MS and they replaced the keyboard, it never happened again.